# possible to create desktop application + web application from Spring Roo Application

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-roo

I am currently exploring the possibility of using [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo) to make a fully fledged CRUD web application. Since Roo is built on top of Java EE and uses beans, JPA for entity management, I was wondering if one can use the same code base to develop a desktop application. I mean with Java EE 6 and eclipse I can make a EJB project for the beans, an EAR (Enterprise Application Project), A Web Application project and everything falls in perfectly. Is the same possible with Roo? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to create a desktop and web application from spring roo, it is possible.

Roo helps automate the creation of an application with a web user interface, but you are pretty much on your own for creating the desktop user interface.  Also, you will have to decide how to connect the desktop user interface to the roo generated application.

Because the roo generated application is just a spring application, you could for example expose your roo services to the desktop user interface using [spring remoting](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html).